# How to get average value of all the fields inside an embedded object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Need to get the avg value of all the fields of an embedded object but each object has another embedded object. So firstly the avg of inner embedded object has to be derived.

Tried few variations. But not getting the desired result.

```
  [{
$project: {
    vals: {
        $objectToArray: "$values"
    }
}
}, {
$unwind: {
    path: "$vals",
}
}, {
$project: {
    valInner: {
        $objectToArray: "$vals.v"
    }
}
}, {
$group: {
    _id: "$valInner.k",
    avg: {
        $avg: "$valInner.v"
    }
}
}]
```

The json looks like this :

```
 {
  "_id": {
 "$oid": "5cf8132d528a1809fc6bad64"
  },
 "values": {
  "0": {
     "0": 0,
     "1": 0,
     "2": 0,
     "3": 0,
     "4": 10,
     "5": 20,
     "6": 0,
     "7": 10,
     "8": 0,
     "9": 0,
     "10": 0,
     "11": 0,
      ...
      ...
      ...
      "57": 0,
      "58": 0,
      "59": 0
     },
"1": {},
"2": {},
 ...
"60": {}
},
 "event_hour": {
"$date": "2019-06-05T19:16:02.524+0000"
}
}
```

Expected Output after the aggregation should be :

```
   {
 "_id": {
 "$oid": "5cf8132d528a1809fc6bad64"
},
 "values": avgValue,
 "event_hour": {
  "$date": "2019-06-05T19:16:02.524+0000"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using the following stages in the pipeline.

1)Project and convert the primary object to an array.
2) Unwind that array.
3)Project and convert the inner embedded object to an array.
4) Unwind it.
5) Group it on id and calculate the average.

```
[
 {$project: {values : {$objectToArray : "$values"}}}, 
 {$unwind: {path: "$values"}},
 {$project: {values:{$objectToArray:"$values.v"}}}, 
 {$unwind: {path: "$values"}}, 
 {$group: {_id: "$_id",hour_avg: {$avg:"$values.v"}}}
]
```